# OnClick SSJS with partial refresh on xp:link control doesnt work?

Tags: xpages

I have the following LINK control on the form and would like to call the managed bean method onclick and do partial refresh (refreshing specifing part of the page). But I just found out, that this doesnt work, I can see that clicking on  link sends XHR request to server, but the managed bean method call (entire onClick SSJS event) is not triggered. If I redesign thi as button controll, thigs are working properly, but I need link in this case. Is it some bug or my misuse of concept?

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="" id="link2" >
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="create_recipe_form_panel">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:F.getRecipe().adjustWt()}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: if the xhr is is getting sent, what is the response you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: misuse of concept. A links should "send you somewhere else" while a button "does something for you". So most likely the link destination and the click action get in each others way. Use a button and give it a class. Play with the css until you have the visual you desire.

Comment: Yes I went the css way ... I just wondered that the LINK control has all these options available ... and it even post form but doesnt run my code ...